# Vanishing of $R^1f_*\mathcal O_X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I am probably missing something obvious here, but none the less, here goes:
Is the following statement (or perhaps some minor modification of it) true and if so, why:
*$R^1f_*\mathcal O_X = 0$ for a finite morphism of curves $f\colon X\to Y$.*
The question is inspired by exercise 4.2.6 in Hartshorne, where it seems to be necessary to use some sort of similar result. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way to see it. This is probably overkill with the machinery. Finite morphisms are proper, and the higher direct images of a coherent sheaf under a proper morphism are still coherent. Thus $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ is coherent.

But now by the Theorem on Formal Functions, the completion of the stalks are just cohomology of the fibers: $\widehat{(R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y}\simeq  \varprojlim H^1((X_y)_n, \mathcal{O}_{(X_y)_n})$. Since the fibers of a finite morphism are finite, the $X_y$ are zero dimensional and hence the $H^1=0$ and hence $(R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X)_y=0$ for all $y\in Y$ which shows $R^1f_*\mathcal{O}_X=0$.

Comment: I very much like the overkill machinery! Does this argument in fact work for arbitrary coherent sheaves? If not, could you please indicate where it breaks down?

Comment: Yes. The same argument in fact shows that if $f$ is proper between any Noetherian schemes and $i$ is bigger than the maximum dimension of the fibers of $f$, then for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ we have $R^if_*\mathcal{F}=0$. (This is actually Corollary 11.2 in Hartshorne).

Comment: Thank you very much! I have previously only browsed the Theorem on Formal Functions section of Hartshorne as I found it somewhat unmotivated. Now, having acquired a newfound respect for this mighty theorem, I will certainly reread it rigurously and thoroughly!